# Android - Libgdx - Couldnt Load File

Tags: android, libgdx, assets

I have used google, read all Questions here on StackExchange but still couldnt solve my Problem.

So Im following a tutorial from kilobolt(Zombie Bird).

The desktop-version of the game is running without problems, but if I want to run it on an android emulator I get this error message:

"Couldn't load file: data/logo.png"

The line where I get the error looks like this:

```
logoTexture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("data/logo.png"));
```

My Android Path looks like this:

-Android
  -Assets
   -Data
    -logo.png

I assume this is the correct path.

I have tried cleaning the project, I used Gradle > Refresh All, I restarted Eclipse. 
Nothing worked.

Im a little bit confused cause if I move the file outside of Data but in the Assets Folder and change the path to this:

```
logoTexture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("logo.png"));
```

It works.

Can someone explain me why I cant use the Data Folder inside of Assets?

Comment: There are chances that it is because asset might not still be loaded.What you can do is in your render method make following change
if(logoTexture!=null){// draw it}

A better approach will be to use asset manager.

Answer (score 1):

What emulator are you using to run it? For me, the same code works properly on an actual Android device, so I'd assume it is an Emulator error. Possibly has to do with the / as the seperator character. This is just a wild guess, but does

```
logoTexture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("data" + File.separator + "logo.png"));
```

fix it, or break it?

Comment: I will try it as soon as possible, I dont assume it was an Emulator problem cause the apk didnt work on my S4 also.

Comment: That is really strange. This type of texture opening did work for me, even in the assets/data folder. Maybe the culprit is elsewhere? Did the S4 throw any kind of error during USB debugging?

Answer (score 0):

maybe it's caused by the difference of OpenGl ES 1 and OpenGl ES 2...

Using OpenGl ES 1 the picture size has the power of two. Bear with me - I'm new to libgdx.. :)